# How do I change a computer name using Windows SIM?

Tags: windows, unattend-file

I'm trying to use Windows SIM to generate a somewhat random computer name for a bunch of new computers we will be deploying Windows 10 using WDS. I know how to use SIM to auto-add the computers to the domain and plan to do so. I do not plan on using MDT since it is not a good choice for my organization.

I want something like LT-DepartmentName-## where the ##s are sequential numbers for each computer imaged. I also don't want them having the same name as another computer in AD. How can I do this? Is it easier just to rename the computer after they are joined to the domain?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have Windows generate a unique computer name, but it might not work the way you had hoped.

1. The computer name is limited to 15 characters, i.e. department name likely won't fit
2. The uniqueness is a random string, not sequential number
3. the generated name is either completely random or based (in part) on the full name and organization name specified in the Microsoft-Windows-Setup -> UserData section of the answer file

For more info see the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-shell-setup-computername